# How to close the workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to close and excel workbook but i can't, it gives me runtime error 1004

i have tried everything on the comment section in the code below.

```
Private Sub April()

'open workbook
Dim fileName As String
Dim directory As String
Dim fileNameLong As String
Dim rpr As Workbook

directory = "C:\Users\.........\Desktop\Rapor"
fileName = dir("C:\Users\.........\Desktop\Rapor" & "\*.xlsm")
fileNameLong = directory & "\" & fileName
Set rpr = Workbooks.Open(fileNameLong)

Workbooks(2).Worksheets(1).Range("bb2").Copy
Workbooks(1).Worksheets(1).Range("a2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Workbooks(2).Worksheets(1).Range("g3").Copy
Workbooks(1).Worksheets(1).Range("b2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Workbooks(2).Worksheets(1).Range("g5").Copy
Workbooks(1).Worksheets(1).Range("c2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Workbooks(2).Worksheets(1).Range("g21:be21").Copy
Workbooks(1).Worksheets(1).Range("d2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False

'save the file to archive later but first to close the excel file. 

Dim saveNameLong As String
saveNameLong = directory & "\Archive\" & fileName
Application.Workbooks(1).Activate
Range("a2").Select
rpr.Close False
'Application.Workbook(ActiveWorkbook.FullName).Close
'ActiveWorkbook.Close
'Application.Workbook.Close False, fileName
'Application.Workbooks(2).Close
'Name fileNameLong As saveNameLong

End Sub
```

runtime error 1004. i can't close the excel workbook.

EDIT:
Ahmed AU .. yes there is a Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean) in th workbook i want to close. is this a problem? how i can get around it?

EDIT(SOLVED):
i just added the application.events = false 
and it worked!!!

Comment: Are you **sure** it's that line causing the error? Try removing the previous line.

Comment: Is it possible the workbook is already open when this code runs?

Comment: Excel won't be able to close a workbook if another workbook is opened and its VBA project is referencing it. Is this what's going on?

Comment: @MathieuGuindon My answer was supposed to be a comment.  I've deleted.

Comment: is there any possibility of `Workbook_BeforeClose` event firing in the  `xlsm` file opened?

Comment: Ahmed AU .. yes there is a Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean) in th workbook i want to close. is this a problem? how i can get around it?